# angularjs component bindings parameter check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

Is there a way to check args with bindings in angularjs?
I want to change the processing by checking args beforehand.

```js
angular.module('app').component('test', {
 template: '<button data-ng-click="$ctrl.click();"></button>',
 bindings: {
  fn: '&',
 },
 controller: [
  '$element',
  function ($element) {
   let $ctrl = this;
   $ctrl.click = function () {
    /*
     let params={};
     if(check($ctrl.fn,'message')){
      params.message='Hi,';
     }
     if(check($ctrl.fn,'now')){
      params.now=Date.now();
     }
     */
    $ctrl.fn({
     message: 'Hi,',
     now: Date.now()
    });
   };
  }
 ]
});
```

```html
<test data-fn="$ctrl.a(message);"></test>
<test data-fn="$ctrl.a(now);"></test>
<test data-fn="$ctrl.a(message,now);"></test>
```

For example, you want to change by calling the test tag.

Comment: Can I implement functions like code comments?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is possible but not desired.
You need somehow redesign this, i.e:

```
<test fn="$ctrl.a(data);" fn-attrs="message"></test>
<test fn="$ctrl.a(data);" fn-attrs="now"></test>
<test fn="$ctrl.a(data);" fn-attrs="message,now"></test>

        $ctrl.click = function () {
            let attrs = $ctrl.fnAttrs.split(',');
            let data = {};
            if (attrs.indexOf('now') !== -1) {
              data.now = 'smth';
            }
            if (attrs.indexOf('message') !== -1) {
              data.message = '';
            }
            $ctrl.fn({ data: data});
        };
```